# Is there way to treat Makefile warnings as errors and halt compilation

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu-make

I used --just-print,--print-data-base, and --warn-undefined-variables command line options to debug makefile.
Is there a way to stop makefile when an warning is found in makefile. Just like werror flag treat warning as error in case of GCC.

Comment: Looks like you collect all tags containing "make" in their name :) Tags `cmake` and `automake` relates to *configuration* systems. If you question purely about Makefiles and `make` utility, drop `cmake` and `automake` tags.

Comment: Thanks Tsyvarev. Did the said changes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to treat a warning as an error in a Makefile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859916/how-to-treat-a-warning-as-an-error-in-a-makefile)